# POST Request Python Web Scraping: Get URLs from Tag

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Hi i am new to both python and web scraping. From my scripts, I want to POST Request and then get the urls from it. But I got a problem, I cant get the urls from the a tag. When I inspect the website I can see the URL but in my script it shows as javascript.
So, I'm looking for some ideas to solve this problem. Thank you.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.adassothai.com/index.php/main/ad_expenditure/'
myobj = {'y': '2014'}

x = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
soup = BeautifulSoup(x.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using post requests data is in json format so you can use that to extract data
from it just use `.json()` method after calling URL and headers are also optional

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36",
        "Referer": "http://www.adassothai.com/index.php/main/ad_expenditure/"
}
url = 'http://www.adassothai.com/index.php/main/ad_expenditure/'
myobj = {'y': '2014'}

res= requests.post(url, data = myobj)
data= res.json()['data']

soup=BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")
```